# Insert into with multiple subqueries as values

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

Lets suppose I've to insert into a table with many fk, just to explain here below the **wrong statement**:

```
insert into mytable
values
(
somevalue
,somevalue
,select id from othertable1 where ...condition
,select id from othertable2 where ...condition
,select id from othertable3 where ...condition
)
```

so basically values to insert comes from different subqueries, is it possible to achieve such a behavior ?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

```
insert into mytable (columns)
select somevalue, somevalue, a.id, b.id, c.id
from
 othertable1 a
 cross join othertable2 b
 cross join othertable3 c
where
 a ... condition
 b ... condition
 c ... condition
```

Comment: I have the same problem but with only two values and othertable1 and othertable2 are the same table: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49025589/nested-select-insert-values-into-table-with-two-subqueries

Answer (score 1):

Can you use a select statement to do the insert?

```
INSERT INTO MYTABLE
SELECT (SOMEVALUE,
    SOMEVALUE,
    T1.ID,
    T2.ID
)
FROM ANOTHERTABLE T1
JOIN YETANOTHERTABLE T2
    ON T1.BLAH = T2.BLAH
WHERE condition1...
```

Comment: I can't use JOIN since ti is not correlated with T2, the cross join was the missing point for me.