# SELECT on INSERT's VALUES

Tags: mysql, sql, insert, sql-update

my question is if there is any way to do this:

```
INSERT INTO t1 (c1, c2, c3, c4, c5)
VALUES (SELECT c1 FROM t2, 15, 2, 'Name', SELECT c5 FROM t4);
```

I know I have the `INSERT INTO t1 FROM SELECT`, but I can't use it for this special case, and I wanted to know if it would be possible to add selects in the insert values.

Comment: Is there any relation between c1 and c5?

Comment: Take a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10900994/insert-into-with-multiple-subqueries-as-values

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sub query use with **`parenthesis`** use right there like:

```
INSERT INTO t1 (c1, c2, c3, c4, c5)
VALUES ((SELECT c1 FROM t2), 15, 2, 'Name', (SELECT c5 FROM t4));
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible, but not in the syntax you mention:

```
INSERT INTO t1 (c1, c2, c3, c4, c5)
SELECT t2.c1 , 15, 2, 'Name', t4.c5
FROM t2, t4
WHERE t2.some_field = t4.some_other_field
```

The `t2` and `t4` tables should have some logical join between them or a `WHERE` condition of their own.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is way to make It. You need to use `parenthesis` for each `SELECT`.

```
INSERT INTO t1 (c1, c2, c3, c4, c5)
VALUES ((SELECT c1 FROM t2), 15, 2, 'Name', (SELECT c5 FROM t4));
```

Remember that your select should return only 1 value.

Answer (score 0):

This should work for you.

```
INSERT INTO `pages` (name, content, modified) 
VALUES ('new page', (SELECT `description` FROM `categories` WHERE id = '4'), NOW());
```

I think you just forgot to put the sub-query in parentheses.

Answer (score 0):

you should use somthing like this:

```
INSERT INTO  t1 (c1, c2, c3, c4, c5)
SELECT
   f1.c1, 15, 2, 'Name', f2.c5
FROM
   (SELECT c1 FROM t2) AS f1
    CROSS JOIN
   (SELECT c5 FROM t4) AS f2
```